# Choose random number from non-continuous range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, numbers

I am trying to get a random number between 3, 4, and 26-29.

I have tried `rand(3, 4, 26..29)`, but was unsuccessful. Theses are product id numbers that I am trying to assign object to randomly.

Any help is beneficially and welcomed.

Comment: @lpapp That only works for a continuous range.

Comment: How is that any different? You get an index and you select that from the set of numbers? It is one no-brainer extra step.

Comment: Then you agree that it isn't a duplicate?  It is useful information though.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a nicer syntax, but this should do the trick :

```
([3,4]+(26..29).to_a).sample
```

Comment: wouldn't this end up adding [3,4] to [26..29] rang?

Comment: .sample method returns a random item